# index Match not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two sheets with the following data within;

Sheet1:

```
Invoice #(A) - Gross amount(B) - Payment(C)
```

Sheet2:

```
Date(A) - Details (B) - Description (C) - Credit (D)
```

I wish to obtain a match from Sheet 2 Credit (D) to Payment(C)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet2'!D:D,MATCH('Sheet1!'B1,'Sheet2'!D:D,0)),"")
```

What is the error in my formula or my approach?

[Here is file that I am working on](https://www.mediafire.com/file/v0u861si9sdnmv0/Book1.xlsx/file)

Comment: Can you provide sample data? and expeced result?

Comment: Well, you have covered up any error with an `IFERROR`, but may I assume your initial error was a `#N/A`, and with your cover up, you got a `""` value? This means, there is no match. This would simply mean, the value you looking for does not excist in the lookup range. Maybe it simply isn't there, but maybe your data looks like it should be there, but for example trailing spaces, or formatting throws your `MATCH` of. We simply won't know until you provide sample data.

Comment: The Match is One to One or One to Many? Could you provide a sample about your problem?

Comment: Are you expecting single value to return or it may match with Multiple values?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your Formula,, now we need some sample data *(Copy & Paste,, as Screen Shot)* to test and better write what error you are receiving !!

Comment: @RajeshS the question asker provided a sample Excel file. Asking for a _Screen Shot_ of text data is not something I would encourage.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke,, yes I've seen the File link,, need to download and work with and return to the OP is quit tedious ,,so that I've written for Screen Shot !!

Comment: @RajeshS again: a *screen shot* of text data does not make sense. How am I going to copy that screen shot into excel? I need to retype it. Why would I do that? So better would be to copy the text data into the question in a structured format _or_ provide the Excel file (as is done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded your file, and it appears that it had something to do with the formatting of the columns.<sup>A nice example why you should always include a sample.</sup>

Steps I've taken:

1. On Sheet 1 select column B and set the formatting to `Number`.
2. On Sheet 2 select column D and set the formatting to `Number`.
3. On Sheet 1 in column C write the formula `=INDEX(Sheet2!$D:$D, MATCH(B2, Sheet2!$D:$D, 0), 1)`

This gives the following result:

```
| Invoice #  | Gross   | Payment |
|------------|---------|---------|
| 62225/0007 | 6608.51 | #N/A    |
| 62225/0016 | 8911.85 | #N/A    |
| 62225/0008 | 6930.37 | #N/A    |
| 62225/0009 | 839.11  | #N/A    |
| 62225/0017 | 6992.62 | #N/A    |
| 62225/0018 | 7450.18 | 7450.18 |
| 62225/0019 | 8173.44 | 8173.44 |
| 62225/0020 | 8323.41 | #N/A    |
| 62225/0021 | 7169.35 | 7169.35 |
```

After you verify that this is correct you can start wrapping it in an `IFERROR` formula and other decorative routines.